# How do you create a company domain for users to login?

Tags: security, group-policy

I'm very new at this so wanted to know how or where do I start?
A path would also be sufficient for getting there.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Are you asking how to register a domain name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AD domain creation (in a nutshell) takes following steps:

1. Set server computer hostname
2. Enable Active Directory Services
3. Promote server to Domain Controller
4. Add new forest, using your domain

After that, reachable clients could register to your AD.

Following articles can guide you through specifics:

- [How to create an AD domain](https://www.whitewinterwolf.com/posts/2017/09/26/how-to-create-an-active-directory-domain/)
- [Windows Domain hackerbook](http://www.thehackerplaybook.com/Windows_Domain.htm)

As an extra, you should set up your domains GPOs:

[Group policy configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/branchcache/deploy/use-group-policy-to-configure-domain-member-client-computers#bkmk_gp) can guide you through group policy configuration to allow clients to login using an specific domain, however this is WS 2016 procedure.

Comment: Thank you gl4ssiest. We already have Azure AD, no domain controller though. Any thoughts on how to leverage the current availability and create domain controller?

Comment: In that case you need to install DC services in your going-to-be DC machine. Check steps 3 -4 of this [guide](http://www.thehackerplaybook.com/Windows_Domain.htm). Reference added to above answer :D

Comment: Okay, so its imperative to have a DC machine for AD? can it be configured over Azure AD in cloud?

Comment: Yeah, you should configure a DC machine, a dedicated server if business infraestructure allows it, or a VM (an  Azure VM in your case)